# MySQL only select certain row

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, mysqli

I have this weird problem. For some reason only certain row is selected. I have this `user_data` table: 
[image]

and `website_name` table
[image]

For some reason with this command using user id `13` it works:

[image]

but using user id `27` it didn't but you can see I add #27 in `email_id` row gumblar.cn.

[image]

Why it won't work with id 27? I'm using this command:

```
SELECT `email_address`, `handset` FROM `website_name` JOIN `user_data` USING ( id ) WHERE `email_id` ='27'
```

Any help and explanation is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a coincidence that id == email_id for 13, you need to change

```
USING ( id )
```

to

```
ON (website_name.email_id = user_data.id)
```

EDIT:

In your table, you see the row:

```
id | website   |email_id
---+-----------+--------  
13 | yahoo.com | 13
```

You see how id is the same as the email_id?  That is just a coincidence, and is why it worked for that number (you are joining on id, which just so happens to match the email_id, which is what you SHOULD be joining on).

Your SQL should look like:

```
 SELECT `email_address`, `handset` 
 FROM `website_name` 
     JOIN `user_data` ON (website_name.email_id = user_data.id) 
 WHERE `email_id` ='27';
```

Comment: Hi, using your command will select all data in `email_address` and `handset`. I only need certain row to work for example when I use id `27` I will get `2k10@gmail.com` email address. Also please forgive my stupidity, what do you mean by `coincidence that id == email_id for 13`. Do you mean that  `website_name` is coincidence to have have id `13`?

Answer (score 2):

You're joining with the id 18 and non of your users has the id 18.

You need to join it with a on statement:

```
join user_data on user_data.id = website_name.email_id
```

Comment: Hi, using your command will select all data in email_address and handset but I can't get to get specific row for example using id `27` will get me `2k10@gmail.com` email address

Comment: this is correct! do you have an email_id field in your user table? If not how do you want to identify the user correspoding to the email domains. You need to add an email_id field in your user table and everything should work fine. Just use than "join user_data on user_data.email_id = website_name.email_id" or using(email_id)

Answer (score 2):

Both of your tables contain a field `id` - but, obviously, they identify different things (emails and websites, respectively). This is why your `JOIN` cannot use the `id` field to produce sensible results (that it worked for 13 is only coincidental and the query result does not make sense). You need to use

```
JOIN user_data ON website_name.email_id = user_data.id
```

A different approach would be to rename the `id` fields to `email_id` and `website_id`. Then, you could use `JOIN user_data USING(email_id)`.

Comment: Hi, using your command will select all data in `email_address` and `handset`. I only need certain row to work for example when I use id `27` I will get `2k10@gmail.com` email address. Also please forgive my stupidity, what do you mean by `coincidence`. Do you mean both table is coincidence to have id #`13`?

Comment: Well, you still have to add the `WHERE` clause just as you did before. Yes, that's what I meant by 'coincidence'.